# Trying to create a subquery using activerecord in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord

I am very new to rails. Thanks for taking a look at this. I'm trying to create essentially a subquery in activerecord. Here is what I have in my controller.

```
 @vote_time = Submission.select("submissions.updated_at").where(:chosen => true).first
 @submissions = Submission.where(["submissions.created_at > ?",  @vote_time])
```

I think this is roughly what it would look like in sql.

```
select * from submissions where submissions.created_at < (select submissions.updated_at from submissions where chosen = true limit 1)
```

Whenever I run the activerecord search @vote_time is inserted as null. Am I just barking up the wrong tree? Can you not pass a variable into an array condition? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You're calling #first, which returns the first submission. If you get nil, there you don't have any submissions returned by the first query.

Comment: When you do a select it will not return the value of that column, it will return a Submission instance with only the updated_at attribute populated. If you have any record in the database matching the conditions you should be able to use @vote_time.updated_at to access the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call the `updated_at` attribute on the first object returned, rather than trying to select only that column. As so:

```
@vote_time = Submission.where(:chosen => true).first.updated_at
@submissions = Submission.where(["submissions.created_at > ?",  @vote_time])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was it. I can't tell you how much I appreciate this.